# Delay Multer file upload

Tags: express, multer

I'm using Multer in a MERN Stack App to upload multiple files when POSTing to create a new Image Gallery.

```
router.post('/gallery', upload.array('photos', 5), galleryController.createGallery);
```

However, I don't want the files to upload until I confirm that a Gallery doesn't already exist for this User.

Does anyone know how to delay the file upload until I have confirmed this Gallery should be created? Or, if that isn't possible, is there a way to "rollback" the upload and delete the images from this upload?

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not get any sort of control of the uploads when you use any of the predefined defaults such as `.single()`, `.array()`, `.fields()`, and more.

You will need to provide a custom `storage` engine in order to accomplish what you're asking. See the docs here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#storage

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    // Do logic to delay the file upload if needed by throwing error
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    // ...
  }
})

const upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did see an example similar to the above that checks for attributes of the files (ex: file size), then determines to upload or not. However, I wasn't quite sure how to delay based on the result of an Async DB query. After looking at your sample code, and thinking this through a bit more, I should be all set. Thanks again!